# Slice image individually, and this is the code how can i make this repsonsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Hi i sliced the image and coded it, but its in fix size, how can i make this responsive? without using bootstrap can u help me ? and this is the whole image of it, [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owdoO.png) you can see the the code below thank you so much

```
<table id="Table_01" width="1001" height="720" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            <img src="images/Info_01.png" width="1000" height="29" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="29" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <img src="images/Info_02.png" width="361" height="4" alt=""></td>
        <td rowspan="3">
            <img src="images/Info_03.png" width="348" height="308" alt=""></td>
        <td rowspan="3">
            <img src="images/Info_04.png" width="291" height="308" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="4" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="images/Info_05.png" width="69" height="289" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/Info_06.png" width="292" height="289" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="289" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">
            <img src="images/Info_07.png" width="361" height="332" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="15" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="images/Info_08.png" width="348" height="317" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/Info_09.png" width="291" height="317" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="317" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            <img src="images/Info_10.png" width="1000" height="66" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="66" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please make a minimal working code sample so we have with what to work.

Comment: without using bootstrap, your best bet is using tables with percentage values. Still going to be tough since your images were cut to have specific heights and widths, not adjustable css values found in responsive sites.